# Trying to understand what this is in python

Tags: python, tensorflow

`(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()`

I'm still in the middle of learning the basic Python functions, and this is from the tensorflow website. What does this line do?

I've already learned Java, but so this is new to me. This line seems to initiate the variables x_train, y_train, x_test, and y_test, but if so I don't understand why there would be four variables formatted in such a manner.

Please explain it to a person who doesn't know Python, but has already learned Java.

According to tensorflow, mnist is a dataset.

Comment: Do you mean what's the purpose or how it's possible to assign the values this way?

Comment: This is a multiple assignment, like `t = (0, 1, (2, 3, 4))` you can try using `a, b, c = t` , and `x_train` contains the image to be trained, `y_train` is the label, which number of the corresponding x_train is marked, `x_test` , `y_test` are used to verify the use of the model at the end, observe the size of the data set

Comment: This is called destructuring.  A tutorial on this topic: [Destructuring in Python](https://blog.teclado.com/destructuring-in-python/)

Comment: You should really search this site, we have very similar questions asked and answered.

Answer (score 2):

If `x = (1,2)` is *binding* a tuple value to a variable.

If `(1, 2)` is a structure.

Then `(x, y) = (1, 2)` is a *de-structuring bind* giving `x=1` and `y=2`.

The structures of variables and data must match. The structure is removed, and the values are bound to the variables in the same position.

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = (1, 2), (3, 4)
```

gives `x_train = 1`, `y_train = 2`, `x_test = 3`, `y_test = 4`.

It's a convenience instead of writing:

```
temp = mnist.load_data()
x_train = temp[0][0]
y_train = temp[0][1]
x_test  = temp[1][0]
y_test  = temp[1][1]
```

or etc.